# how add sms verification to legacy IIS application

Tags: authentication, nginx, iis, reverse-proxy, arr

We have legacy application hosted on IIS and now we would like to add additional authentication (using sms code). What is the simplest way to do it?

My current idea is to use reversy proxy:

1. proxy will redirect all request to authentication application,
2. authentication application will check an authentication cookie,
3. if cookie exists and is valid authentication application will return 200,
4. if cookie is not present or is not valid authentication application will show html page to enter user login and then sms code, if code entered by user is valid authentication cookie will set and application will return 200,
5. if sms code is invalid authentication application will return 401,
6. if the applicatoin returns 200 proxy will redirect user to main application.

Is it possible to use IIS reversy proxy / Application Request Routing? Or maybe is it better to use another proxy, for example nginx?

Comment: ARR URL rewrite are being executed before application logic. So you could only use {HTTP_COOKIE} variable to do some simple authentication with regex expression. You may need to build up a front-end application to authenticate the cookie then do rewrite manually. Of course, httpmodule could be inject to do some simple authentication in some case.

Comment: Ok, I will read about HTTP_COOKIE. Thanks.